# How to swipe through activities with labels?

Tags: android, material-design, swipe

How can I add this labels with arrow below a toolbar?

[image: Lables]

By that I want to make a transition - with the help of an animation - from one activity to the other.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom toolbar. First create your toolbar_layout.xml and place whatever you want (including your label and arrows) into that layout. Then add the following to your activity_layout.xml:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
```

And finally add the following to your activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Yeah I already knew about the toolbar..but Im stack in the design section. Thanks for the answer!